# add subview in window based application

Tags: iphone

I have started making a window based iphone application in which I have added tabbar and navigation controller. In tabbar there is 5 tabs. Now On first tab I have added a button, On the click of button I want to add a subview but this view should not be from other 4 tabs, it must be different from them. Can It possible? If anyone know then please help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrameCGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
myview.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[tabbar1 addSubview:myivew];
```

tabbar1 is the view where you want to add the new view.